# Add random data from listview items into Textview

Tags: java, android, listview

When you click the button as it appears in the code, the data in the edit text is added as a list view.

When I click the button, I want to add a random data from the listview items and add it in the textview.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView listgor;
    EditText textgir;
    Button katgir;
    Button kuraceker;
    TextView katilimcisecer;


    ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        data.add("Hello World");

        listgor = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listeler);
        textgir = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.sira1);
        katgir = (Button) findViewById(R.id.katilimciekle);
        kuraceker = (Button) findViewById(R.id.kuracek);
        katilimcisecer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.katilimci) ;


        listgor.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, data));
        katgir.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View currentView) {
                data.add(textgir.getText().toString());
                textgir.setText("");
            }
        });

    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add data from listview items to `TextView` use code below.

```
int randomIndex = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0, data.size())
yourTextView.setText(data.get(randomIndex))
```

Comment: I want to add a random data.

Comment: @BlackWood I've updated my answer to use random item.